# Book about reflections in windows and mirrors?

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

All I remember about this young adult fiction book is that it is about a younger boy who gets caught up in some big fantasy adventure involved with looking at your reflection. Mirrors are dangerous because they show people too clearly for who they are while windows are good because they change your reflection a little. In the end the boy somehow gets aligned with the window-reflection people and has to perhaps get his soul back from the mirror people, though I do not remember this part exactly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When would you have read this?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?

Comment: There's Stephen R. Donaldson's _[Mordant's Need](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordant's_Need)_ duology, which is all caught up in mirrors and reflections, but it involves a young woman rather than a buy.

Answer (score 5):

I think the book is called [The King in the Window](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/7113.The_King_in_the_Window) by Adam Gopnik.

> During dinner with his parents one cold January evening, Oliver feels silly wearing the paper crown of an Epiphany-festival French king. That night, looking in the mirror, he sees a boy in an ancient French doublet gazing back at him. The boy, Francois, tells Oliver that he himself is kingly, and that he has a special mission--rescuing souls. Only days later, on a trip to Versailles, Oliver is transported to the French spirit kingdom, ruled over by the fatuous King Louis the Nth. There, the famous playwright Moliere tells Oliver he must deliver France from the forces of the great Egg, who sucks up the spirits of men, women, and children when they look into a mirror of glass or of water.

I was trying to find it too but it's almost as if it didn't exist.